# looping through multi dimension array

Tags: php

I am parsing A JSON file in PHP using PHP Decode

```
$json= file_get_contents ("resultate.json");


$json = json_decode($json, true);
```

and then I am trying to loop through the results and display them

```
 foreach($json as $zh){


$name = $zh[0]["VORLAGEN"][0]["JA_PROZENT"];
$JA = $zh[0]["VORLAGEN"][0]["VORLAGE_NAME"];
$kreis = $zh[0]["NAME"];
$kreis1 = $zh[22]["NAME"];




 echo $name;
 echo $JA;
 echo $kreis;
 echo $kreis1;
    ...}
```

but I receive only one element e.g. position 0 or position 22. I would like to receive all the results and display them in a list. Below you can see the array

```
Array
(
    [GEBIETE] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [VORLAGEN] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [VORLAGE_NAME] => Kantonale Volksabstimmung über die Vorlage Steuergesetz (StG) (Änderung vom 1. April 2019; Steuervorlage 17)
                                    [JA_STIMMEN_ABSOLUT] => 205
                                    [STIMMBETEILIGUNG] => 28.11
                                    [NEIN_STIMMEN_ABSOLUT] => 183
                                    [VORLAGE_ID] => 2491
                                    [JA_PROZENT] => 52.84
                                )

                        )

                    [NAME] => Aeugst a.A.
                    [WAHLKREIS] => 0
                    [BFS] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [VORLAGEN] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [VORLAGE_NAME] => Kantonale Volksabstimmung über die Vorlage Steuergesetz (StG) (Änderung vom 1. April 2019; Steuervorlage 17)
                                    [JA_STIMMEN_ABSOLUT] => 1000
                                    [STIMMBETEILIGUNG] => 26.15
                                    [NEIN_STIMMEN_ABSOLUT] => 851
                                    [VORLAGE_ID] => 2491
                                    [JA_PROZENT] => 54.02
                                )

                        )

                    [NAME] => Affoltern a.A.
                    [WAHLKREIS] => 0
                    [BFS] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [VORLAGEN] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [VORLAGE_NAME] => Kantonale Volksabstimmung über die Vorlage Steuergesetz (StG) (Änderung vom 1. April 2019; Steuervorlage 17)
                                    [JA_STIMMEN_ABSOLUT] => 661
                                    [STIMMBETEILIGUNG] => 30.98
                                    [NEIN_STIMMEN_ABSOLUT] => 454
                                    [VORLAGE_ID] => 2491
                                    [JA_PROZENT] => 59.28
                                )

                        )

                    [NAME] => Bonstetten
                    [WAHLKREIS] => 0
                    [BFS] => 3
                )
```

can you please tell me how to print  all the elements of this array?

Answer (score 1):

There is `GEBIETE` layer in your json, so change `foreach($json as $zh)` to `foreach($json["GEBIETE"] as $zh)` will works.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest multiple `foreach`:

```php
$root = $json['GEBIETE'];

foreach ($root as $elem) {
    foreach ($elem as $key => $value) {
        // VORLAGEN is an array of its own so if you want to print the keys you should foreach this value as well
        if(is_array($value)) {
            foreach ($value[0] as $k => $v) {
                echo $k."\t".$v;
            }
        }
        else {
            echo $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you but I do get  Notice: Array to string conversion for echo $v; and echo $value

Comment: Sorry, I missed the fact that 'VORLAGEN' is actually two levels deep. Updated the answer, should work now.

Comment: Note: the code is quite tightly knit to the structure you presented, so be aware of that. Although you can generalise it, if your format is not gonna change it's probably not worth it.